# Display control from one form to another in Visual Basic 6

Tags: forms, vb6, controls, display

Let's assume i have a VB6 projects with 2 forms (let's call them formA and formB). In formA i have 2 text boxes (call them txtBox1 and txtBox2) and formB is empty. Is there a way to display txtBox1 and txtBox2 from formA to formB. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that.  What you *can* do is add 2 text boxes (again, we'll call them txtBox1 and txtBox2) to FormB.  To display the contents of the two text boxes on FormB, do this:

```
FormB.txtBox1.Text = FormA.txtBox1.Text
FormB.txtBox2.Text = FormA.txtBox2.Text
```

If FormA is the current one, you can write `txtBox1.Text` instead of `FormA.txtBox1.Text`, in the usual manner.  Similarly, if FormB is the current one, you don't have to specify FormB.  But you do have to specify the form that isn't the current one.

Comment: +1 Your answer is the correct answer for this question. Just for fun I will say that you can [reparent a control from one form to another](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_reparent.html) but that doesn't make a copy of the control, it just moves it - and usually there's a better solution to your problems.

Comment: Interesting point.  As you say, I can't really think of a reason to do that offhand, but it's an idea to file away.